# Invalid conversion from 'char *' to 'char' when using char array in class

Tags: c++, class

This class takes in a name, job title, which are both stored in a char array, and age. An “Invalid conversion from ‘char *’ to ‘char’ occurs when I run the program. I believe I am using the char arrays incorrectly, but am unsure what the issue is. The program works perfectly when using strings. Can you explain what I am doing wrong and how to fix my code? Please also explain how the errors show me what is wrong.

Thank you in adavance.

**Header file (emplyee.h)**

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

/*No need for passing arguments into the functions since they can
 * call the variables declared in the private access specifier. */

class Employee
{
private:
    char Name[20], Jobtitle[30]; //Why not working ?
    int Age;

public:
    Employee(char, int, char);
    char getname(); /*Could having the name of the function the same as the variables cause a problem ? Yes it will*/
    int getage();
    char getjobtitle();
};

#endif // EMPLOYEE_H
```

**Source File (employee.cpp)**

```
#include "employee.h"

Employee::Employee( char n[20], int a, char j[30] )
{
  Name = n; Age = a; Jobtitle = j;
}

char Employee::getname()
{
   return(Name);
}

int Employee::getage()
{
   return(Age);
}

char Employee::getjobtitle()
{
   return(Jobtitle);
}
```

[**Error messages print screen**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPR0F.png)

Comment: You need to revise your book on arrays and pointers. It'a difficult subject but extremely important if you are going to write code using arrays.

Comment: For instance this is not correct `Employee::Employee( char n[20], int a, char j[30] )
{
  Name = n; Age = a; Jobtitle = j;
}` It should be `Employee::Employee( char* n, int a, char* j )
{
  strcpy(Name, n); Age = a; strcpy(Jobtitle, j);
}`

Comment: Remember that you cannot pass an array to a function, return an array from a function, copy arrays using `=`. These things are done using pointers instead, which is why you need to revise your book on arrays and pointers.

Comment: `char` ≠ `char[20]`

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid char arrays (in most situations i.e. -03 is not good enough for what you want)**

Use std::string. This is how it would look like.

**Employee.h:**

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H

#include <string>

class Employee{
    private:
        std::string Name, JobTitle;
        int Age;

    public:
        Employee(std::string Name, int age, std::string JobTitle);

        std::string getName();
        int getAge();
        std::string getJobTitle();
};

#endif
```

**Employee.cpp**

```
#include "employee.h"
#include <string>

Employee::Employee(std::string n, int a, std::string j){
    Name = n;
    Age = a;
    JobTitle = j;
}

std::string Employee::getName(){
    return Name;
}

int Employee::getAge(){
    return Age;
}

std::string Employee::getJobTitle(){
    return JobTitle;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "employee.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    Employee e("Hemil", 16, "NA");

    std::cout << e.getName() << "\n"
          << e.getAge() << "\n"
          << e.getJobTitle() << "\n";
}
```

**Note: This will not work in Turbo C++**

Answer (score 0):

```
char getname();
```

means you are gonna return one char which is not correct because

```
char Name[20]
```

is a char array so you may want return the pointer to that array (which is of type char*)  so your prototype should be

```
char* getname();
```

same goes for title

Comment: "is actually char*" - no it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here
```

Name and Jobtitle are arrays of char's you should use
`strcpy(Name, n);` and
`strcpy(Jobtitle, j);`.

Your `getname` and `gettitle` functions should be written as:
`char *Employee::getname()`
`char *Employee::getjobtitle()`.